# Encrypt data for particular type of users in the same data table using SQL server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have a studies table where all users save their studies. I want to encrypt the row entry in the table for particular user type while saving, and decrypt when showing on web page (example: for paid users). For others, data is stored directly.

Can any one guide me on to achieve this? I've never worked on encryption. I googled and found out about Asymmetric keys, symmetric keys and AES encryption.

Please help me decide which one I have to use. And please let me know, is it necessary to encrypt data on both the SQL side and the application side.

Comment: Are you mixing up authorization with encryption perhaps? If you want to encrypt the data only for paying users, use a separate table and use SQL Server's encryption support. You are still just as liable though if the sensitive data of unpaid users is lost, so what's the point? If you want to *restrict* what each user sees, you are looking for separate separate views or row-level security.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :  According to requirement I cannot add separate table I have to encrypt in the same Studies table. 
Separate views, studies are users' property so User only can see his studies saved previously. People cannot see some others data.

Comment: VIews like tables are SQL object, not users' property. And tables *do* get partitioned. That's an implementation detail, *not* a requirement of any kind. If you don't want people to see other people's data, just add the proper filter when reading from the database, eg `WHERE UserID=@someID`. A stored procedure or function can make that a lot easier. Finally, if you really want row-level security, use SQL Server 2016. Encryption is *not* an authorization mechanism. It *can't* be used as a way to restrict access. Encryption protects against people stealing your disk or your sa password

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I appreciate your response. Thanks. I got confused, (thought about showing on view engine), current version is working like as you said, by fetching by comparing with user Ids. Actually the need is to save paid users data in encrypted form just to give them a feel like no one can see their data.(As whats app is showing end-to-end encryption message now a days )